# Quads appear in front of others while they're not

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to write a simple Doom style game, and for that matter i've decided to write a block-type engine (much simmilar to Minecraft), however i have ran into a problem: The blocks render really oddly, with parts of blocks passing through like nothing is there.

This is what happens when you look at quad from left:[image: left]
However, when you look at it from right, everything looks perfectly fine: [image: right]

Let's get to the code, shall we?
This is how i initialise OpenGL:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(fov, (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight(), 0, -2);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

I render block's faces using display lists. I tried using VBO's, but changed to display lists, as i thought they caused the problem. Every display list looks generally the same:

```
        glNewList(listTop, GL_COMPILE);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        tex.bind();
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x+0.0f, y+1.0f, z-1.0f); 
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x+0.0f, y+1.0f, z+0.0f); 
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y+1.0f, z+0.0f); 
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x+1.0f, y+1.0f, z-1.0f); 
        glEnd();
    glEndList();
```

And then there's rendering:

```
glClearColor(0, .5f, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glPushMatrix();

          if(rTo)glCallList(listTop);
          if(rBt)glCallList(listBot);
          if(rFr)glCallList(listFront);
          if(rBk)glCallList(listBack);
          if(rLe)glCallList(listLeft);
          if(rRi)glCallList(listRight);

            glPopMatrix();

    glLoadIdentity();
    //Display.update() etc here
```

So, what might be causing this bug? Anyone had simillar problems?

Comment: did you enable and initialize the depth buffer ?

Comment: Where do you request your OpenGL context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see that you are enabling the DEPTH TEST,

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Also, you have to clear the depth buffer on every frame.

Try to do that before rendering your scene, since it looks that objects are being incorrectly overlayed. Also, I think that you shouldn't set your near value in the projection matrix to Zero, since it may cause you some troubles later.

Comment: I also said the "near value" thing! But anyway, is good to know that it's working fine now :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice that :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out i didn't enable GL_DEPTH_TEST. While that was the problem, it was not the only one. The biggest problem was in *gluPerspective* method, the zNear was set to 0, i learnt that it needs to be above 0. So,changing this line:

```
gluPerspective(fov, (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight(), 0, -2);
```

To this:

```
gluPerspective(fov, (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight(), 0.1f, -2);
```

AND enabling GL_DEPTH_TEST fixed everything :)

Comment: `gluLookAt` has nothing to do with `zNear`. Your problem was `gluPerspective`. You cannot use **0** because that messes with the math used to compute perspective depth; you **can** use **0** if you have an *orthographic* projection matrix though.

Comment: I should also add that enabling the depth test alone is usually insufficient. You can run into a situation where your framebuffer actually has no place to store depth, so you need to make sure you have a non-zero value for depth bits when you select a pixel format. Likewise, you should clear the depth buffer somewhere in your code if you use depth testing.